# Two separate wordpress installations at one domain

Tags: database

so I have this wordpress website [knivesreviews](https://knivesreviews.net/)

I ha ve blog section there, but it really is just category. I would like to make it separate wordpress installation, but I'm afraid it will mess up my database. I want it it separate installation,because I will be adding eshop with knives to the original website and need it to be on separate database for security and other reasons. What is the easiest way how to have two installations of wordpress at one site and is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can install another wordpress site at subdomain eg: subdomain.example.com. In your cPanel, you can point your subdomain to particular folder where you hosted the eshop site.

Answer (score 0):

install it as another sub domain or in a different directory from your main site